# Polymer website not working in firefox and IE browser but in in the Chrome It will work?

Tags: polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

I have create a Ecommerce website using polymer it wil be properly working in a  chrome but in the Firefox and IE it will be not wroking.i got a syntax errot like: "," missing statement error.please tell me how to fix this error?[image]

Comment: Can you share your code or at least a piece of code where we can reproduce the error?

Comment: Which code i have to share ? mean i have a multple function?

Comment: I can't tell you what's going wrong if I can view and test the code